# Are neural sensitivity tests used in proving/refuting Freudian and Neo-Freudian theories?

Tags: neuroscience, personality, psychoanalysis, experimental-neuroscience, freud

Given that Freudian theories root their explanatory models in neurology (that is, selected extra-sensitive (erogenous) body zones), has any scientific study tried to prove/refute them, by measuring the sensitivity of those zones through modern neurological testing methods and then exploring correlations with purported personality traits?

(I tried to discover such research myself with no result. I guess I am not using the right search phrases.)

For those needing more context, Freud comes up with the concepts of anal, urethral and oral characters. Far-fetched modern interpretations such as [Applied system-vector psychoanalysis](https://psy8.net/pages/about) go as far as trying to explain high neurological sensitivity of eight specific body zones as a consequence of evolutionary adaptations and define accordingly, specific character traits and psychosomatic vulnerabilities.

Comment: This might shed some light: https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/cross-check/why-freud-should-be-dead/

Comment: I read the whole article and I did not find anything relevant to my question (with the far-off exception that I learnt that a discipline of Neuropsychoanalysis existed). This article was probably meant to summarize conclusions from previous insights about Freudian theories, with their specific arguments and evidence. On its own, though, it does not contain such and it definitely does not mention any neurological testing as a research method.